# Maven Release plugin not committing files others than pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have a project that contain MANIFEST.MF, we have a private maven plugin that when building package, modify the Manifest file.

we are using release:prepare and release:perform, the problem is that the commit done by release:prepare only change pom.xml file and not the others files modified when building. any idea how to add these files to the same commit ?

we use the plugin like this

```
mvn  --batch-mode build-helper:parse-version -DpushChanges=false release:prepare -DdevelopmentVersion='${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT' -DscmCommentPrefix='[maven-release-plugin][skip ci]' && mvn --batch-mode -DlocalCheckout=true release:perform && git push origin --follow-tags
```

Comment: When does the custom plugin change the content of the manifest file during the usual life cycle?

Comment: Could you tell me which "other files" you are talking about? The version change happens in the POM, and this seems alright with me.

Comment: during package cycle, if i execute mvn package our private plugin will take some info from pom.xml and put them in Manifest file

Comment: change are made to MANIFEST.MF

Comment: What kind of changes are made in the MANIFEST.MF. You know that you can add manifest entries out of the box via maven-jar-plugin for example?

Comment: This solution works for me :) Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77678103/297907

Answer (score 2):

You can't. 
And it's not what a good build process should do IMHO.

Your build process should only guarantee that if you execute the build process later on the exact same commit, it will give the exact same result.

So why should it commit the changed manifest file? 
If you run the build later with the same commit, will it not also change the manifest file again in the same way?

In cases like this, your plugin should not actually change a manifest file that is checked in, but should *generate* a manifest file in the `target/` directory instead, and use that for the build. It could use the original manifest file as a template, but should not change it.

Comment: Thank for response, we need to make sure that the version of pom.xml file is the same that manifest.mf version
for exemple if pom.xml contain 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, the manifest file should contain Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier 
when incrementing version using release plugin we need to make sure that the bundle version match

Comment: Then create the MANIFEST.MF during the build with the correct version. Or use it as filtered resource and reference `${project.version}`.

Comment: we dont create Manifest.mf file, the file already exist we just need to make sure the version match, 
the modification of manifest file is done during build phase

Comment: Altering a file that is in source control during the build is a sin. If you don't want to create it, try with filtered resources. Don't modify a file during build and then put it into source control.

Comment: This solution works for me :) Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77678103/297907