# How to update version in non pom files using maven release plugin

Tags: maven, versioning, git-commit, maven-release-plugin

I've a maven project and I'm using the maven-release-plugin to prepare the release.

When I run the `mvn --batch-mode release:prepare` command, it creates two commits as follows

> (HEAD -> develop) [maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development
> iteration
>
> (tag: myapp-1.0.0) [maven-release-plugin] prepare release
> myapp-1.0.0

This correctly updates all the pom files.

but I've some text files in my project where there is a version token. I'm looking for a way to replace these version tokens appropriately as per the commits.

For example, the `prepare release` commit should replace the token to `1.0.0` and `prepare for next development` should replace the token to `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

I've checked the documentation but didn't find any way to do this. If somebody has any ideas on how to achieve this through maven-release-plugin or with the help of any other plugin, please suggest.

**EDIT:**

This issue is not solved even if I place the files inside resources directory. The thing I've observed is that the release plugin only selectively adds the `pom.xml` files in the commit, not other files even if they are modified gets added into to the commits pushed by release plugin.

Let me clarify I am not looking for replacing version in the source file and have it replaced in the generated artifact. We can argue about why there is version field in non source file, but there are genuine scenarios anyone can think of.

As a developer I want that the release commit made by the maven release should be accurate i.e. It should contain all the changes associated with that specific release version.

Comment: If those files are correctly put into `src/main/resources` and you've configured to filter them it should be done...?

Comment: @khmarbaise These files are at the root level

Comment: In the root level they do not belong there. Can you explain what kind of files are they?

Comment: Some are documentation related files, and few values.yaml override files for hem charts

Comment: I can strongly recommend to put them into a different directory and configure to filter them (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) or make an appropriate configuration and keep them at the root location if you like.

Comment: @khmarbaise added an edit to question, please check

Answer (score 0):

As khmarbaise said: Use `${project.version}` in the respective files, put them into a resources directory and use filtering.

Comment: The release plugin will only change the POM. Other files are filtered during the build.

Comment: **Vote** for [this feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-798)

Comment: Why do you need this? I don't see that. You can easily put the version number in all resources without any changes to the release plugin.

Comment: because manually putting is not possible in huge multi module project.

Comment: I guess you have not understood my answer. What you need to do: 1. You put `${project.version}` everywhere you need the version number. 2. During the build, the expression `${project.version}` will automatically be replaced by the actual project version. So there is not need to write something like `1.0.0` into every file, just write `${project.version}`.

Comment: As I already said, some are documentation files and some are helm values files, some are changelog files. I want the version to be updated in **source files** as well, not just in the release artifacts

Comment: Why do you need this in source files?

Comment: ok. not in source file. but how do I do it in changelog

Comment: @Vivek You got any valid solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to update version in non-pom files using maven release plugin.

- placed ${target.file} in src/main/resources and added @project.version@ in ${target.file}
- added 2 plugins  **maven-release-plugin** and **maven-resources-plugin**. Details added at the end
- In release process

  - src/main/resources/${target.file} copied to ${project.basedir}
  - @project.version@ replaced with latest release version
  - pom file ${project.basedir}/${target.file} committed in [skip ci][maven-release-plugin] prepare release

**maven-release-plugin**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <preparationGoals>resources:copy-resources@update-project-version scm:add -Dincludes=${target.file}</preparationGoals> 
                    <checkModificationExcludes>${target.file}</checkModificationExcludes><!-- I dont want to update snapshot version in target file so I have excluded that from "prepare for next development iteration" -->
                </configuration>
                
</plugin>
```

**maven-resources-plugin**

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.7</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <delimiters>
                                <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                            </delimiters>
                            <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>update-project-version</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>${target.file}</include>
                                            </includes>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        
</plugin>
```